# How to save a file with react-native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to download and save a file with [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob). (I haven't been able to do it without a library since apparently react-native only implements a subset of the browser's `fetch` interface). My code is something like:

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'

RNFetchBlob
  .config({ path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/medias/foo' })
  .fetch('GET', 'http://example.com/files/foo', { 'Cache-Control': 'no-store' })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('file saved to ' + res.path())
  })
```

and I'm getting:

```
[RNFetchBlobRequest] session didCompleteWithError (null)
[RNFetchBlobRequest] session didBecomeInvalidWithError (null)

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: No such file '/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0781956D-D2E6-4BC8-8943-62DA9B111BEF/data/Containers/Data/Application/A39E6A35-D248-4019-9CA0-1F9063E40161/Documents/medias/foo'
Error: No such file '/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0781956D-D2E6-4BC8-8943-62DA9B111BEF/data/Containers/Data/Application/A39E6A35-D248-4019-9CA0-1F9063E40161/Documents/medias/foo'
    at createErrorFromErrorData (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1824:15)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1777:25
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2135:16)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1952:16
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2070:9)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1951:12)
    at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:72:58
```

The file is not created, the 'medias' directory in the (virtual) device remains empty.

**How to download and save a file with react-native?**

Comment: Try using this RNFS.
https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try again rn-fetch-blob, I ended up using react-native-fs and it works. react-native-fs seems more popular and more maintained.

(I did a react-native version upgrade before trying again to save a file, so maybe it wasn't entirely due to a bug in rn-fetch-blob but also due to using an old react-native version.)

Answer (score 3):

let try this.

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'
import Share from 'react-native-share'
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import {Alert, Platform} from 'react-native'

const download = (url) => {
  let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
  try {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const configOptions = { fileCache: true }
      RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions)
      .fetch('GET', url, {
      'Authorization': '', //yourTokenIfHave
      'Content-Type': '' // 'application/octet-stream'
    })
    .then(resp => {
      return resp.readFile('base64')
    })
    .then(async base64Data => {
      base64Data = `data:application/pdf;base64,` + base64Data
      await Share.open({ url: base64Data })
      // remove the image or pdf from device's storage
      await RNFS.unlink(filePath)
    })
} else {
  RNFetchBlob
    .config({
      fileCache: true,
      path: dirs.DocumentDir + `/${itemPDF.fileName}`
    })
    .fetch('GET', url, {
      'Authorization': '',
      'Content-Type': '' // 'application/octet-stream'
    })
    .then(async (res) => {

      // the temp file path
      if (res && res.path()) {
        const filePath = res.path()
        let options = {
          type: 'application/pdf',
          url: filePath
        }
        await Share.open(options)
        await RNFS.unlink(filePath)
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    }
  } catch (error) {
   console.log('download: ', error)
 }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet has an indentation issue. But thanks for pointing to https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share , which is undoubtedly the cleanest way to save files since it asks the user where it wants to save it, and is cross-platform!

Comment: @ThomasP. They don't allow an option to save to camera roll which is what many of us want

Answer (score 0):

You problem appears to be with the permissions access to that dir, `.config({ path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/medias/foo' })`, probably because `/medias/foo` does not exist, try to do it without a specific path.

I always use it in this way, as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob):

```
RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
    // this is much more performant.
    fileCache : true,
  })
  .fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.zip', {
    //some headers ..
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // the temp file path
    console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
  })
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I want my files in a specific location and not in random locations. I need to keep track of files easily.

Comment: then check if `medias/foo` is a valid path

Comment: Yes with a shell I can create files in `medias/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, if you are using "rn-fetch-blob": 0.10.14 switch to "0.10.13", check https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/266 &
https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf/issues/286

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample function to download the file and save it to the appropriate file path. Keep in mind this is a generic function so please tweak it according to your use case.

```js
const downloadFile = ({
  fileExt
}) => {
  ReactNativeBlobUtil.config({
      fileCache: true,
    }).fetch('GET', filePath)
    .then(async(res) => {
      ToastAndroid.show('Download Successful', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      // in iOS, we want to save our files by opening up the saveToFiles bottom sheet action.
      // whereas in android, the download manager is handling the download for us.
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        ReactNativeBlobUtil.ios.openDocument(res.data);
      } else {
        await ReactNativeBlobUtil.MediaCollection.copyToMediaStore({
            name: fileName,
            parentFolder: `${ParentFolder}/${fileExt.toUpperCase()}`, // it will store the file in this path
            mimeType: fileType
          },
          'Download', // Media Collection to store the file in ("Audio" | "Image" | "Video" | "Download")
          res.path());
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('BLOB ERROR -> ', err));
}
```

Keep in mind copying to the media store is the most important part. You can also ask for storage permissions from the user before downloading.